# "ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error" when bypassing tnsnames.ora using full connection string and EZCONNECT

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, odbc, pyodbc, tnsnames

Attempting to use either connection string to bypass tnsnames.ora (full connection string and EZCONNECT) returns the following error when trying to connect to the database:

> pyodbc.Error: ('HY00', '[HY00] [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error\n (12560) (SQLDriverConnect);[Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error\n (12560)')

I've tried using the following connection strings from https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/:

```
Driver={Oracle in OraClient11g_home1}; Data Source=uid/pwd@//host:port/service_name;

Driver={Oracle in OraClient11g_home1};
Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host)(PORT=port))) 
                         (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=service_name)));
User Id=uid;Password=pwd;'
```

I can connect to the database using sqlplus and EZCONNECT:

```
PS: C:\>sqlplus uid/pwd@//host:port/service_name

SQL*PLUS: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Thu Aug 30 11:56:22 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle. All rights reserved.

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

SQL>
```

I doubt it's a driver issue, because using a different driver returns a different error:

> pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Why does the connection string work for sqlplus but not for ODBC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use the Oracle ODBC driver then the connection string should be like this:

```
Driver={Oracle in OraClient11g_home1};
DBQ={(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host)(PORT=port))) 
                         (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=service_name)))};
Uid=uid;Pwd=pwd;
```

See [Oracle in OraClient11g_home1 connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle-in-oraclient11g_home1/)

For the [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/odbc-driver-for-oracle?view=sql-server-2017) Microsoft driver it would be

```
Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};
Server={(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host)(PORT=port))) 
                         (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=service_name)))};
Uid=uid;Pwd=pwd;
```

See [Microsoft ODBC for Oracle connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-odbc-for-oracle/)

Please note, the *Microsoft ODBC for Oracle* is available only for 32-Bit

Comment: I've marked this as accepted because it did answer the question and is the correct connection string, but it returns a different error:

`pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08004', '[08004] [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified\n (12154) (SQLDriverConnect)')`

Looking at other Stackoverflow answers suggests that this is because of a 32bit/64bit difference, even though the OraClient driver and database are both 64bit.

Comment: Is your python also 64-bit? Perhaps you have to remove the curling brackets `{}` around the database name.

Comment: Python is a 64-bit install of version 3.6.5. Removing either set of curly brackets makes no difference.

Comment: I also made some test, looks like for ODBC you must use an alias. Full qualified names seems to be not supported neither by Oracle nor the Microsoft driver.

Comment: For the host? I've tried using the IP address and hostname without the domain and it still results in the 12154 error.

Comment: This problem was fixed by adding values for TNS_ADMIN and TNS_HOME as environment variables and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE` that point to the `\NETWORK\ADMIN` directory of the Oracle installation. This meant I could use tnsnames.ora and simply use `Driver={Oracle in OraClient11g_home1};Dbq=tnsnames_entry;Uid=username;Pwd=password;` as the connection string.

So it seems that this isn't possible without using tnsnames.ora